# Pre-order Fill a tree from file

Tags: c

I was wondering if you could help me out I'm really stuck on this code I wrote. I'm supposed to pre-order fill a tree from a file that is structured in the following way.

```
    Hello
    goodbye
    yes
    '    ' <- This is an actual space in the file
    no
    end of file
```

When ever there is a space I wanna return back to the node previous and go right and return whenever it reaches EOF. 
So the text above would be structured in the following way

```
                         hello  
              goodbye            null no right child

            yes    no
```

This function is supposed to fill my tree in preorder. I'm grabbing the data using my readFile function here

```
    char *readFile(FILE *fp)
{
   int c = 0;
   int i = 0;
   size_t capacity = 10; 
   char *arr = NULL;
   char* temp = NULL;
   arr = (char*) malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
   while (((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
   { 
  if(capacity == (i+2))
       {
   capacity *= 2 ;
   temp = (char*)realloc(arr,capacity * sizeof(char));
    /*Assigns Address to newly allocated array*/ 
    arr = temp;
      }
    arr[i] = c;
    i++;
    }
   arr[i-1] = '\0';
    if(arr[0] == '\r') /* Line spaces to move up*/
     {
    printf("Got here SPACE\n");
    arr[0] = ' ';
     }
   else if(c == EOF)/*if its an end of file return*/
     {
   printf("Got here EOF \n");
   arr[0] = ' ';
      } 
 return arr;
 }
```

My recursive algorithm to fill the tree is called populate. I'm not really that great at recursion but I've walked though my code multiple times and can't see what's obviously wrong. Currently it seems I can only print the root. Trying to read the left or right root data gives me an immediate seg fault

```
    void populate(FILE *fp,struct node *root)
   {
    char *data = readFile(fp);
    if(data[0] == ' ') /*possible issues with usingn null charater?   */ /*statement is true for both EOF and spaces*/
   {
     return;
    }
     printf("Creating Node\n");
     if(root == NULL)
     {
     root = createNode();/* create the current root */
     root->data = data;/*assign data*/
     }
     printf("%s\n",data);
     populate(fp,root->left);
     populate(fp,root->right);
   }
```

my main

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {   
     FILE *fp;
     node *root = createNode();
     fp = fopen("qa.db","r+");
      if(fp == NULL)
     {
     printf("File not open");
     } 
    populate(fp,root);
     if(root == NULL){
        printf("Equal to NULL\n");
     }
     printTree(root);
     /*check = checkFile(fp)*/
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

Comment: populate() cannot change root* in the caller.  If it starts as NULL, it will forever remain NULL.

Comment: Really sorry what do you mean? In my main function I am initially setting root to a new node before passing it in. I've added my main function.

Comment: 'root = createNode();/* create the current root */ loads the local parameter with a pointer to a new node.  That local is lost when the function returns.  Put another way, 'populate(fp,root->left);' does not, and can not, modify 'root->left'.

Comment: Ok I understand what your saying.  Thank you for the help!  Any suggestion on fixing this? Should I create all my nodes that I need in an array somewhere in my main?

Comment: Nah - try changing the signature to 'node *populate(FILE *fp,struct node *root) ', add a 'return node' at the end and call like root->left=populate(fp,root->left);'.  Something like that, anyway....

Comment: That what I was about to do! Thanks Ill try it out! Appreciate your help!